# Ember Model is never fetching belongs_to relationship, likely due to PK, but others work

Tags: ember.js, model

Ember is returning data for other relationships, so not sure why this isn't working.

**user_model.js**

```
Models.User = DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr("string"),
  firstName: DS.attr("string"),
  lastName: DS.attr("string"),
  ncesHighSchoolId: DS.attr('number'), //should map to #ncesHighSchool.schid

  role: DS.belongsTo("role"),
  zipcode: DS.belongsTo("zipcode"),
  ncesHighSchool: DS.belongsTo("ncesHighSchool"),    

  formattedSchool: function(){
    var schoolId = this.get('ncesHighSchoolId');
    if(schoolId){
      var school = this.store.find('ncesHighSchool', schoolId);
      var schoolLabel = null;
      if(schoolLabel){
        schoolLabel = school.name + ' - ' + school.city + ', ' + school.state;
      }
      return schoolLabel;
    }
  }.property('ncesHighSchoolId')
});
```

**nces_high_school_model.js**

```
Models.NcesHighSchool = DS.Model.extend({
  schid: DS.attr("number"), //this is the primary key, not a normal id field, can't use id field
  name: DS.attr("string"),
  city: DS.attr("string"),
  state: DS.attr("string"),

  users: DS.hasMany("user")
});
```

In my handlebars template:
`{{role}}` and `{{zipcode}}` both return valid objects, i.e. `<VdConsumer.Role:ember636:3>`
`{{ncesHighSchoolId}}` returns nothing, but if I take out `ncesHighSchool` from user_model.js it returns correctly. Having just the ncesHighSchool belongsTo relationship and not `highSchoolId` property, nothing works. 
{{formattedSchool}} returns nothing (sometimes in fiddling I have gotten it to return the function text itself

I need to have direct access to the ncesHighSchoolId property for a typeahead, but cannot figure out why the belongsTo isn't working for the ncesHighSchool object.

I suspect the non-trivial usage of schid as the primary key, but not sure how to fix, since 
`this.store.find('ncesHighSchool', this.get('ncesHighSchoolId'));` does get the object correctly, but feels hackish the way I'm doing it in `formattedSchool`

[image: Ember Console chrome extension showing empty hash for highSchoolObject]

Comment: schid in your Models.NcesHighSchool might be the source of the issue as ember data expects the key to be "id". How about you give this a try:
//extracted from http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_serialize 

App.NcesHighSchoolSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serialize: function(record, options) {
    var json = this._super(record, options);

    json.id= json.schid;
    delete json.schid;

    return json;
  }
});

Comment: also search for "normalizeHash" in http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_serialize, if that doesn't work

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I will investigate these and post back when I have arrived at a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything with my entire architecture was fine, but I overly relied on Rails-esque abilities of needing ncesHighSchoolId as a separate attribute in my user model. Ember did not like having both `ncesHighSchoolId: DS.attr('number')` and `ncesHighSchool: DS.belongsTo("ncesHighSchool", {async: true })` in the model. In order to get my typeahead to work, I had to cowboy up and do some extra processing. Important parts included for future readers.

**edit.hbs**

```
{{input type="text" placeholder="School Name" value=ncesHighSchool.schnam}}
```

**user_edit_view.js**

```
App.UserEditView = Ember.View.extend({
  afterRenderEvent: function(){
    var ctrl = this.controller;
     ......
    function(event, school){
       if(school && school.id){
         ctrl.store.find('ncesHighSchool', school.id).then(function(ncesHighSchool){
           ctrl.set('ncesHighSchool', ncesHighSchool);
         });
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless your related model objects are side-loaded, you should include the `async: true` property:

```
role: DS.belongsTo("role", {async: true}),
zipcode: DS.belongsTo("zipcode" {async: true}),
ncesHighSchool: DS.belongsTo("ncesHighSchool" {async: true}),
```

Comment: Thanks again for this, definitely helped narrow down possible issues.